# Google Play Game Services - unable to sign in to Game Center

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

Things I've done so far:

1. added and linked my app in the Dev Console (game services)
2. included the  App_id into my app/manifest
3. added BaseGameActivity and GameHelper to my project (from GitHub)
4. added the google-play-services library to my project
5. extended BaseGameActivity

What is ee in log:

```
GameHelper: **** APP NOT CORRECTLY CONFIGURED TO USE GOOGLE PLAY GAME SERVICES
 GameHelper: **** This is usually caused by one of these reasons:
 GameHelper: **** (1) Your package name and certificate fingerprint do not match
 GameHelper: ****     the client ID you registered in Developer Console.
 GameHelper: **** (2) Your App ID was incorrectly entered.
 GameHelper: **** (3) Your game settings have not been published and you are 
 GameHelper: ****     trying to log in with an account that is not listed as
 GameHelper: ****     a test account.
```

1. I took App_id from console, it's 100% correct.
2. I'm trying to log in with an test account
3. SHA1 and package name 100% correct.

How can i check where is the problem?

p.s. i see Client ID in console, looking like:
165********6-****.apps.googleusercontent.com

Should i use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) you should add different SHA1 in different Client ID.

Initially, I added debug and release SHA1s in one Client ID  - not working. Created two different Client ID - now work.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at our [troubleshooting guide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting). It covers many common setup issues and in our experience it solves 80% of problems. Also, the previous sentence contains an arbitrary percentage.

Comment: I would have accepted this answer because it is the answer from the person who wrote whole code for game service :)

Answer (score 0):

You only want to use the numbers "165**6-**" in the client ID. Do not add the ".apps.googleusercontent.com" part.

[Link](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#application_id)

[Better link, see Note text](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#d_gather_credentials_for_authentication_and_authorization)